# How to parse some JSON Code

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to parse this JSON code sample:

```
{
"licenses": [
    {
     "id": "TN",
     "value": "ar"
    },
    {"id": "FR", "value": "fr"} ,
    {"id": "GB", "value": "en"} ,
    {"id": "US", "value": "en"} 
]
}
```

I have this HTML web page to do it using the JQuery plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
<title>Your New Application</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-       scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<style type="text/css">
    /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
    *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255,   255, 0); }
    input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
    body { background-color:white; color:black }
</style>
<script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* This code is used to run as soon as Intel activates */
    var onDeviceReady=function(){
    //hide splash screen
    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
    };
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="pays.json" target="_blank">Open JSON file</a><br />
<input type="button" value="Get and parse JSON" class="button" />
<br />
<span id="results"></span>

<script src="libs/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<script>

    //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //after button is clicked we download the data
        $('.button').click(function(){

            //start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "pays.json",
                //force to handle it as text
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

                    //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                    //and pass downloaded data
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //now json variable contains data in json format
                    //let's display a few items
                    $('#results').html('Plugin name: ' + json.licenses[0].id + '<br  />Author: ' + json.licenses[0].value);
                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S: The JSON file is under the same folder than the HTML web page.
The problem is when I hit the "Get and parse JSON" button, nothing is displayed!

Comment: Try using firebug or similar to see if your ajax request gets executed and if there is some sort of error along the way.

Comment: `force to handle it as text`. Why?

Comment: What is the JS error? Also, lots of issues in codes: 1. you mix-use the jQuery & traditional JavaScript; 2. use `<meta charset="utf-8" />` instead; 3. Do not use `*` in CSS; 4. mix of use of single quote & double quote

Comment: Try console.log($.parseJSON(data));     to see what is inside it, an empty object or something else.

Comment: This is the output of this HTML code:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / index.html:1**

Comment: I tested it on Google Chrome and I inspect the error:

**Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. file:///home/myuser/Documents/pageweb/TestFailedPages/pays.json
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/myuser/Documents/pageweb/TestFailedPages/pays.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Comment: Another thing, I am working with the new intel XDK IDE, and I tested the following tuto: [link]http://runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery[link]... I tested it with the intel XDK emulator, it works, but not with the Google Chrome :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);
```

Reference: [Jquery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

You can also try this:
http://phpjs.org/functions/json_decode/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Surely it will helpful

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "pays.json",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
               $.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
                   alert(obj.id);
               }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use log statements to see where you program is getting to, and could also provide a error function as a function that will be executed if your ajax calls fails which could be the case here.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pays.json",
    //force to handle it as text
    dataType: "text",
    error: function(x, status, msg) { console.log("Failed ajax request with status: " + status + " - " + msg);
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);

        var json = $.parseJSON(data);

        console.log(data);

        $('#results').html('Plugin name: ' + json.licenses[0].id + '<br  />Author: ' + json.licenses[0].value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is the output ** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /index.html:1 **

Comment: I tested it on Google Chrome and I inspect the error:
**Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. file:///home/myuser/Documents/pageweb/TestFailedPages/pays.json XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/myuser/Documents/pageweb/TestFailedPages/pays.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Comment: Another thing, I am working with the new intel XDK IDE, and I tested the following tuto: [link]http://runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery[link]... I tested it with the intel XDK emulator, it works, but not with the Google Chrome :(

Comment: You can't use ajax to access files like that, you may be able to use a relative url on other browsers. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787

Answer (score 0):

in xdk intel my solution --> 
 `success:function(data, textStatus, request){
             var d = JSON.stringify(data);
             alert('hello success : '+ d);
             var e = JSON.parse(d);
             alert('access_t:'+e.Access_token);
         }`